# What would the perfect human race be like?

Tags: humans, artificial-intelligence, genetic-engineering, social-norms

In considering issues such as scientology for human cloning, disease-free DNA, agelessness and physical attributes such as personality, build and complexion; the question is, "what would the perfect human race be like and how would they be mass produced/reproduced?"

Comment: Welcome  to the site.  While an interesting post its not quite right for how the site works.  The first concern is the *opinion based* nature of what perfect is.  The second problem is you have two difficult questions that could support big answers in a single post.  In this case they should probably be broken apart.  Take a peek at the [help] to get a better idea of expectations on writing good Qs and As.  Feel free to drop by [chat] if you have questions as well.

Comment: The range of "perfect" humans is as broad as the range of environments in which humanity might wish to thrive.  Triple-redundant DNA with check sums might be overkill for most environments but you will want it if the nuclear missiles start flying.  Your question is unanswerable but should result in a nice shopping list of high-tech upgrades for my next visit to the genetic swap shop.

Comment: they would be perfectly themselves, or perfectly dead. :wink:

Comment: Go browse webMD. They wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

In reviewing comments above, I believe that Star Trek is the greatest science fiction universe ever; however they clearly are flawed. If they weren't it would be a boring show. As for a "perfect" race short of Q, one must consider that they too will have disadvantages but would co-exist with each other and their planetary system symbiotically.

This would first require either an intelligence capable of creating the delicate balance of population growth and consumption of material, or a lack of sophistication to the point of minimal population growth (aka, death and birth rates relatively even) and global impact.

In either scenario my own supposition requires peace, and so they would need to have a deeply shared moral code. I would consider the following virtues to be required: compassion, courage, empathy, being equanimous (ability to maintain composure), forgiveness, being humble, honesty, a sense of justice, patience, prudence, temperance, and tolerance.

As for physical being I keep thinking of water bears, which are already near perfect. Low metabolism with minimal hunger and health impact, disease and bacteria resistant, also water bears incorporate DNA of other organisms into themselves to improve upon their resistance.

If we're talking humans then think Superman's personality, Wolverine's health, Bruce Wayne's or Captain America's sense of civic responsibility, and Lex Luther's intelligence.

The rest can be extremely subjective based on personal aesthetics.

Answer (score 0):

What they would be like would be pretty relative and opinionated.  What my perfect human being may be, would probably not be your perfect human being.  We can consider what globally would be desirable such as disease-free and ageless but that is basically where the buck stops.

Physical looks is highly opinionated based on regional tastes.  To the Asians, the fairer the skin, the more "wealthy" you are and beautiful.  People who are tanned would be considered poor people who work in the fields and undesired.  Inversely, people in American society love a tanned look.  Being tanned shows that you have the money and disposable income to work on looks, go outside and tan instead of work.  Take a vacation to a beach.  Tanned is considered attractive because it shows they are outdoorsy and athletic.  Being athletic though isn't entirely desirable in terms of physical traits by everyone either.  Some cultures think that a plump person is beautiful or at least it shows status of having money to provide food and eat where as someone who lacks money, may not be as well fed.

Ultimately there are just too many factors to create a perfect human race that appeases to every culture.  You would be better off creating a sentient being who is a humanoid that started out as a collective conscious similar to that of the Borg in Star Trek.  This then eliminates the difference of opinions and culture as they are then assimilated into 1 mind and then assimilate others to improve their intellectual property.

If you were to take Earth though, and try to force this perfect being, socially, it just would not be possible as no one would be able to agree about every aspect of what would be perfect.

**EDIT:** Possible solution to appease the situation.....Create a human that cannot die to to sickness, and cannot be born with mental or physical issues.  That solves the first issue.  Once you have those things eliminated out of the way, you can turn Birthing into a selection process.  A couple goes to a Facility that states what they want in their child.  Looks, smarts, athletics, what ever it is they hope for their child.  You could either have this be a clone creation or have it so that the parents' seeds would be used.  So the mother's egg and the Father's sperm would be used and modified to create desired results.  This then takes away the cultural issues and any difference of opinions based on societal taste as it allows for each person to customize their child using the base template of a perfect human that cannot die unless by murder.

Comment: Respectfully, substituting the Star Trek example for a legislative resolution; what would the perfect "package" look like and what DNA Easter eggs would it contain?

Comment: @Habatchii, that's my point though, there is no perfect package.  Once you get past the DNA issues like disease free, virus free, mutation free, have perfect clean DNA so that deformations, and mental disorders are no longer a birthing issue and so on, it is all relative and opinions from there.  Even if you go ageless, our bodies still have a decay and natural death rate at I believe 150 years old in perfect condition without medical influence.

Comment: @Habatchii There is the option of nanobots going in and repairing dead and decaying tissue possibly in the near future: http://www.computerworld.com/article/2528330/app-development/nanotech-could-make-humans-immortal-by-2040--futurist-says.html but even still that only solves the MEDICAL issues that relate to a perfect human.  As far as physical appearance, that is relative to culture as I explained in my answer.

Comment: When you ask legislatively,  You could create a legislation for a clone army so that real humans don't die in battle.  This then creates the issue that people will be clone right activists and call this inhumane.   But things like appearance wouldn't be a trait  that would matter because the clones would be designed to blend in or at least mimic the look of the country who is creating them.  Everyone would agree though that these clones would need super human strength as well as superior critical thinking ability and intellect that enables faster choices than that of a normal human.